# Need help with potentiometer for DIY magnetic stirrer

Tags: potentiometer, amperage

I am looking to make a DIY magnetic stirrer for cleaning 3D printed resin models. In principle, the setup is not very complex; a motor, potentiometer, power supply. The problem is I am a novice when it comes to electronics. I have a PC case fan that I would like to use for the motor ([specs here](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/sunon-fans/PMD1208PMB1-A-2-GN/1021223)).

I know that the power supply (probably a standard wall wart) will be 12 V. Is there a particular amperage that the power supply should have? Also, what size of potentiometer will I need? I would prefer that the potentiometer have on/off capabilities but if not I can install a switch fairly easily.

I did come across this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CvMDlG_AF3Q&t=357s) that uses a MOSFET but I don't know if/how this would work for my particular project. As I said, I am a novice so detailed instructions and links to parts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't just use a potentiometer to control the speed of a motor. The simplest way possible is probably to purchase some simple PWM module. Google something like "PWM motor speed controller" and you'll find something suitable. It need to be capable of 1 Amp or more for that fan.

Comment: That 2-WIre Brushless DC fan motor is not intended to have its speed controlled. Look for a 3 or 4-wire fan instead - that kind has a speed-control input.

Comment: @brhans The fan that I have is a different model with 3 wires (black, red, yellow). The model number on the fan is the same as the link I posted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Speed Control for a 12v DC PC Fan for Magnetic Stirrer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/184805/speed-control-for-a-12v-dc-pc-fan-for-magnetic-stirrer)

Comment: @ElliotAlderson that does look very similar to what I am trying to accomplish but I don't understand how the diodes would work. Per Klas-Kenny's suggestion, I looked around and found this [DC Motor Speed Controller](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08G4PQ2FW/?coliid=I1R0ZR5VZ5EVVH&colid=3QX52VCFQMUXH&psc=1&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it) which I am hoping would provide the solution.

Comment: That's probably not going to work very well with the brushless motor in your fan. Since you say you have a 3-wire fan, you need a PC Fan speed controller similar to [this](https://www.amazon.com/Comidox-Temperature-Control-Controller-High-Temp/dp/B07LBLWYZF/ref=asc_df_B07LBLWYZF/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=533458241275&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=3695898960187817313&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9010758&hvtargid=pla-1280681830294&psc=1) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple motor speed control. just connect this in series with the motor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKVjgw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The  MOSFET circuit in the you-tube video will also work

For your supply so long as it meets meets the voltage requirement (12V) and meets or exceeds the amperage written on the fan that is enough.